# sum of all columns for each row in DolphinDB database

Tags: row, dolphindb

For a table with around 100 columns, how can I quickly calculate the sum of all columns for each row in DolphinDB? Looks like all DolphinDB functions for a table apply to columns, not rows.

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB's aggregate functions indeed apply to columns. Unfortunately, you'll have to write out this summation yourself (or write some code that generates it):

```sql
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 + /* etc... */ AS sum_of_cols
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB provides a built-in function named `rowSum` that exactly does what you want.

```
t = table(...)
rowSum(t)
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?rowSum).